# When plot a list, how to Manipulate a sequence of defined functions at the same time?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

I am trying to plot a sequence of functions, for example{(a+b)^i},{i,1,100}. All the expressions I have stored in the list. Now I want to plot them and see how their value would change if I change variable b. I defined test2 as the stored sequence and give the a the value of 1.
I tried, `Manipulate[ListPlot[test2], {b, 0.1, 0.22, 0.01}]`, but it doesn't work.
Could you give me some suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `Manipulate[ ListPlot[Table[(1 + b)^i, {i, 1, 100}]], {b, 0.1, 0.22, 0.01}]`?

Comment: Yes, the point is that you need to make the dependence of the first argument of Manipulate on b explicit.

Comment: If the expression inside the `ListPlot` becomes unwieldy, you could take advantage of `With` for value injection inside the Manipulate expression, so you can define the values separately. Functionally it will lead to the same result, but it may be more readable. For instance: `With[{ yourtable = Table[(1 + b)^i, {i, 1, 100}] }, Manipulate[ ListPlot[ yourtable ], {b, 0.1, 0.22, 0.01}] ]`

Comment: Thank you guys! However, what I said is just an example. What I wanted to do is more complex: I cannot simply use Table[(1 + b)^i, {i, 1, 100}] and the sequence is a function sequence constructed by substitution.

Comment: For instance, call this sequence I want to analyze as A. I know A[[0]]=f(a,b), and I know A[[1]]=g(A[0]), A[[2]]=g(A[1]),...etc. After I constructed the A sequence, I want to plot all of them and analyze them using Manipulate function. It's not easy to simply use Table function to finish this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can construct your list within the argument of manipulate using `NestList` ([see its documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)). This function applies a function you give it (e.g. your $g$ function) to an argument repeatedly.

For instance, the following expression starts from the value $2$, applies the pure function `3# &` to it (= "take the argument, multiply it by 3"), and reports the result, then repeats the process on this result. This is repeated a total of $5$ times:

```
NestList[3# &, 2, 5]

(* Out: {2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486} *)
```

You can use this to construct a recurrence based on any starting point, including a variable one whose value you can control with `Manipulate`. For instance, in the following we take a starting value that depends on $b$, the `Manipulate`d variable, then apply the function `(10+#/2&)` it ten times (which is also a value you could control from Manipulate, if you wanted), and plot the resulting list of values:

```
Manipulate[
   ListPlot[
    NestList[10 + #/2 &, 10 b, 10], 
    PlotRange -> {0.5, 110}
    ],
  {{b, 3}, 1, 10}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this works. I will try it.

Comment: @Aguang glad to hear it, let me know how it works out for you